# react-native-facebook-login returning errors when I try log user into firebase

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, redux

I have tried every way I can think and am running into the same issue all day.

I am building a react native mobile application. I am using firebase as my database and react-native-facebook-login package to log the user in.

Currently the package works fine, I enter the fb details and the correct data is being returned and the user is 'logged in', I can console log the result but trying to do anything else returns an error.

I have tried:

Passing an action (Redux) where I do the firebase login, error:

```
Cannot read property 'loginUser' of undefined
```

setState to the resulting data, error:

```
this.setState is not a function
```

I am not sure exactly how to do the firebase authenticate with credentials but am happy to figure that out later, I just need to be able to access the data in the first place!

My component:

```
...
class FBLoginWrapper extends Component {
   state = { user: null };
   render() {
   return (
      <FBLogin
         buttonView={<FBSignInView />}
         ref={(fbLogin) => { this.fbLogin = fbLogin }}
         loginBehavior={FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native}
         permissions={["email","user_friends"]}
         onLogin={function (e) { this.props.loginUser(e); }}
         onLoginFound={function (e) { this.setState({ user: e }); }}
      />
   );
}
...
```

If you need more code let me know. I have included two different ways I have tried and failed under [onLogin] and [onLoginFound]. I will use one implementation for both when I have something that works.

Ideally I would like to call the action {this.props.loginUser(e)} but if I have to do it through a setState that is fine too at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the onLoginFinished property if you just need to access the data returned.

This is how I use the LoginButton in one of my apps:
AccessToken is part of the FBSDK package

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken
} = FBSDK;

....

<View>
<LoginButton
  publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
  onLoginFinished={
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        alert("login has error: " + result.error);
      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert("login is cancelled.");
      } else {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
          (data) => {
            let token = data.accessToken.toString();

            global.storage.save({
                key: 'loginState',
                rawData: { 
                    token: token
                },
            });

            firestack.auth.signInWithProvider('facebook', token, '')
            .then((user)=>{
                Actions.tabbar({profile:user});
            });
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
  onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go. Just to check, is AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() from somewhere? Do I need to import it from a package?

Comment: updated code above, AcessToken is part of the FBSDK package. 
But the result of the Facebook Login Call is inside the result property..

Comment: hmm, unfortunately I am using react-native-facebook-login not the FBSDK - I will give your flow a go though and see if I can get it working with the other package

Comment: oops sorry mate.. didn't realize that.. :-/ have a try yeh, I've implemented it a few times by now, and it works pretty well.

Comment: One of those times when I got it working and I am not 100% sure how, changing many things and suddenly it just started to work - but my code still looks the same as above :s
Given I still can't get the credential to work I will try your firestack recommendation!